# Simulate disk errors, make filesystem go readonly

Tags: linux, debian

I want to simulate a problem some of our servers have had with the filesystem going readonly when connection to the NAS goes down. Is there a quick way to cause the root filesystem to go readonly in a healthy system?

I tried

```
mount -o ro,remount /dev/sda1
```

but got

```
mount: / is busy
```

If it helps I'm running Debian 6 (Squeeze)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe just SysRq+U (force remount all filesystems readonly) will be enough for the test?

If keyboard is not available, it can be done with `echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger`